# How to save the values of an array within an hidden input field before it gets replaced with a new array

Tags: jquery, jquery-filer

I have an application where users can upload images into database through a form. A maximum of 6 photos can be uploaded. User can either select 6 photos simultaneously or can select photos individually max 6 times prior to submitting the form. I then have a hidden input field that gets the file name selected as per below.

```
<div id="content" >
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="filer_input2" multiple>
    <input type="hidden" class="mediafile" name="mediafile"/>
</div>
```

The problem is when user clicks the upload area the hidden input field looses data previously stored. Below is the jquery bit and a screenshot without input being hidden for demo. I would like to know how can I get the file names added to the input field instead of replacing it when user selects a file 2nd or 3rd time....

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#filer_input2').change(function(){

        var files = $(this)[0].files;
        var output = "";
        if(files.length > 0){

       for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            output += files[i].name+",";
        }   

        $(".mediafile").val(output);

            } 
        });
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Is your form posted normally or with AJAX? In case it is normal postback, you will surely loos the values unless you don't persist it server side and set it once the form submitted successfully and you get response.

Comment: form is posted normally with php

Comment: Well, then you have to store already selected filenames on server side using session or in cookie or Local Storage once form submitted successfully. so you can retrieve and apply your validation easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you having this problem, below is how I fixed this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#filer_input2').on('change',function(){
            if(!$(".mediafile").val()){
        var files = $(this)[0].files,
            output = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            output += files[i].name+",";
        }           
        $(".mediafile").val(output);

            }else if($(".mediafile").val()){                    
              var prev_input_file = $(".mediafile").val();
              var new_files = $(this)[0].files,
              new_output = "";
              for (var j = 0; j < new_files.length; j++){
                new_output += new_files[j].name+ ",";
              }
             $(".mediafile").val(new_output + prev_input_file)
           }

        });

});
```